# How to scrape hidden phone number from website using Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data about house listings on the website http://immobilienscout.de. So far, I managed to scrape all the needed data except one thing: the phone number of the listing agent.

Problem is I can't understand the path to reach the text.

Let's say for example that I want to find the price. My code for finding would be the following:

Html code:

```
<div class="is24-phone palm-hide" data-is24-phone-number-block="" data-ng-show="!showPhoneNumbers" data-position="top">
            <div class="is24-show-phone-button print-hide hide">
              <span class="fa fa-phone font-lightgray"></span>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="internal-link"><font><font>Show phone number</font></font></a>
            </div>
            <div class="is24-phone-number">
              <p>
                  <span><font><font>Mobil:</font></font></span><font><font> 0162 2056442</font></font></p>
              <p>
                  <span><font><font>Phone:</font></font></span><font><font> 030 72021143</font></font></p>
              </div>
          </div>
```

My code looks like this:

```
link = "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/96068611"   
html = urllib2.urlopen(link)   
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

findMobile = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'is24-phone-number'})
print findMobile.text.strip()
```

The output in None. Instead I need the output to be: 0162 2056442.

Any help?

Comment: You'll have to use `Selenium` or send a direct request to the api ( `https://www.immobilienscout24.de/anbieter/api/branchenbuch/v1.2/realtor/002.01004402519?clientId=expose` )

Answer (score 0):

If you open the page e.g in Chrome, you should be able to right click what you want to scrape and hit "Inspect Element". Then, in the view of the DOM that pops up again, right click the element and select Copy > Copy selector. That should give you a css selector that looks something like

```
#sidebar > div.module.community-bulletin > div > div:nth-child(10) > div.bulletin-item-content > a
```

Then, you should be able to select that element by just doing

```
soup.select("#sidebar > div.module.community-bulletin > div > div:nth-child(10) > div.bulletin-item-content > a")
```

Edit: Here's the documentation for `.select()`: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Here's an example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224417/how-to-scrape-hidden-phone-number-from-website-using-beautiful-soup-4/45224481#45224481")
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.select("#comment-77415832 > td.comment-text > div > span.comment-copy")
[<span class="comment-copy">I tried to use your code for the element I am interested but the output is an empty list. Any ideas how to solve this?</span>]
```

Comment: I tried to use your code for the element I am interested but the output is an empty list. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Make sure you're copying the selector correctly. I've added an example to my post showing how to get the span containing your comment. In your case, it looks like you want to be right clicking the innermost <font> element and copying the selector for that.

Comment: Hey it does not work. It returns an empty list. Why is it, could there be some sort of encryption?

Comment: What the other user said is correct. Since the content is generated dynamically, you can't simply get it via urllib. You'll have to use something like Selenium or headless Chrome.